# Can't get the value of the selected Div into a hidden Input

Tags: javascript, html

I’m stuck on getting a path value from a set of selectable div's. Its part of a project of converting classic ASP to dot net. There are other posts on this subject, but didn't see one that matches my situation.

This is the HTML code that is presented for  the users selection. It is a list of available folders.

```
<b>Select the destination:</b>
<div id="destinationSelector">  <div style="padding-left:45px;"     value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER\SUBSUBFOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBSUBFOLDER</div>

<div style="padding-left:30px;" value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER</div>

<div style="padding-left:15px;" value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;ANOTHER FOLDER WITH     FILES</div>

<div style="padding-left:15px;" value="C:\Test Folder">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;Test Folder</div>

<div style="padding-left:30px;" value="C:\TEST FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER</div>

<div style="padding-left:15px;" value="C:\TEST FOLDER WITH FILES">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;TEST FOLDER WITH     FILES</div>

<div style="padding-left:15px;" value="C:\TEST MOVE FOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;TEST MOVE FOLDER</div>

</div>
<input name="moveto" id="moveto" type="hidden" />
```

Javasript is supposed to pickup on the path selection, change the backgrond color, and transfer the div value to the hidden input value, moveto. I can then pickup that value in the code behind.

I added a couple of window.alerts to the javascript to troubleshoot. I varified that the javascript triggers when a div is selected. However, the value is always null. Here is the code:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
            $("#destinationSelector>div").live("click", function () {
                window.alert("You Clicked the Path Selection for Move");
                $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#fff');
                $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
                $("#moveto").val($(this).val());
                window.alert($(this).val());
            });
          });
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

After looking at the helpful responses, I recoded using data-value in the HTML and the following Javascript:

```
        $("#destinationSelector").live("click", function () {
            window.alert("You Clicked the Path Selection for Move");
            $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#fff');
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
            window.alert($(this).data('value'));
            $("#moveto").val($(this).data("value"));
        });
```

Also tried:

```
window.alert($(this).attr("value"));
```

The Window.alert comes back as undefined.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been long deprecated.

Comment: Hi, I tried using .on and it didnt work. Also didn't show up in intellasense.   $("#destinationSelector>div").on("click", function () {

Comment: You're probably using jQuery version 1.7 or below then.

Answer (score 1):

`value` is not a valid attribute for the `<div>` element - and therefore jQuery has no ability to return it via `.val()`.

Instead I would suggest you use `data-value="..."` and then use `.data("value")` instead

```js
$(function(){
  $("div").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-left:30px;" data-value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER</div>
```

---

As stated by @melancia in their comment, if you can't update the HTML, you can use `.attr("value")` instead of `.val()`.

However, `data-value` is valid under W3C checking, and `value` isn't, so I'd go with the above example if possible.

```js
$(function(){
  $("div").click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="padding-left:30px;" value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
<img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER</div>
```

Comment: If you're unable to change the markup, use `$(this).attr("value")` to retrieve the value instead.

Answer (score 1):

as noted divs don't have values.  you need to use the data- attribute.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#destinationSelector>div").live("click", function () {
    window.alert("You Clicked the Path Selection for Move");
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#fff');
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ccc');
    $("#moveto").val($(this).attr('data-value'));
    window.alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Select the destination:</b>
<div id="destinationSelector">
  <div style="padding-left:45px;"     data-value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER\SUBSUBFOLDER">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBSUBFOLDER
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;" data-value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:15px;" data-value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;ANOTHER FOLDER WITH     FILES
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:15px;" data-value="C:\Test Folder">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;Test Folder
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:30px;" data-value="C:\TEST FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;SUBFOLDER
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:15px;" data-value="C:\TEST FOLDER WITH FILES">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;TEST FOLDER WITH     FILES
  </div>
  <div style="padding-left:15px;" data-value="C:\TEST MOVE FOLDER">
    <img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />&nbsp;TEST MOVE FOLDER
  </div>
</div>
<input name="moveto" id="moveto" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: Hi, I coded it exactly as your (and others) examples and it comes back as undefined. My html has the data-value change as well.                                                                     <div style="padding-left:45px;" data-value="C:\ANOTHER FOLDER WITH FILES\SUBFOLDER\SUBSUBFOLDER"><img src="../graphics/icons/closedfolder.gif" />SUBSUBFOLDER</div><

Comment: well that's interesting.  It works in the snippet the way you want? If so then you need to post your entire code as a working snippet.  ARE YOU USING JQUERY 1.8 OR LOWER?

Comment: jquery-1.3.2  Let me see if I am able to update, as this is a locked down system.

Comment: I modified the snippet so it will work with jquery 1.3.2

Comment: YOU ARE DA MAN !!!  When I switched to Jquery 3.3.1, it broke a lot of functionality. I tried your version for 1.3.2 and works fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have `val`, I would recommend changing value in your div to `data-value`

Then using this to get that string:

`$("#moveto").val($(this).data("value"));`

or you can try this without changing the div

`$("#moveto").val($(this).attr("value"));`